# Redirect Curl request with data

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP curl request which works - However, if i set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` as `1`, the Curl post is submitted with the postdata, the redirected page HTML is captured and posted on my localserver.

The entire redirect is contained within my local server and it doesnt actually transfer me across to the redirection itself with the data (which is what i want). After a few seconds of the html being downloaded on my post.php, it redirects to a page not found.

However, if i set the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` as `0` and then fetch the correct URL and then redirect it through `header("Location: $redirect");` - it transfers fine but there no more data being transferred.

What would be the best way of transferring that data to the new header location.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'postdata=' . urlencode(xmlGrab()));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

// Download the given URL, and return output
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$headers = substr($output, 0, $curl_info["header_size"]); //split out header
$redirect = curl_getinfo($ch)['redirect_url'];

header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
header("Location: $redirect");

// Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

**Example Scenario:**

- User Submits a post http://localhost:8888/post.php
- Post.php contains a connection to google.co.uk
- Post.php connects and makes a post to google.co.uk
- The request downloads google.co.uk?q=blahblah to post.php
- post.php looks exactly like google.co.uk?q=blahblah
- 3 seconds later, it redirects to http;//localhost:8888/?q=blahblah

Comment: "then adds it back onto my local server" - huh? Not sure what you meant with that. Please rephrase it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath added a bit more explanation

Comment: Sorry, don't understand that either.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Added a use case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `$redirect`.

If it's a relative url you have to prepend the protocol+hostname+etc to the url, otherwise you'll end up on your local server.